# Recreating an SQL query in JavaScript ES6

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to rebuild a big SQL pipeline in JavaScript so that it can be run as a serverless CRON job without having to spin up a new database. As I'm working through it, I'm at a point where my data looks like the this:

```
const orders = [
    { email: 'test@test.com', orders: '11111111', daydate: 2017-07-29, revenue: 59.99 },
    { email: 'test1@test1.com', orders: '22222222', daydate: 2015-07-29, revenue: 52.99 },
...
]
```

And the next SQL query is here:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT(email),
    EXTRACT(month from min(daydate)) as month_acquired,
    EXTRACT(year from min(daydate)) as year_acquired
FROM orders
GROUP BY email
```

I'm wondering what the best way to go about rebuilding this query in JavaScript is?

I started out by trying to get the distinct emails with the following statement:

```
const distinctEmails = orders.filter((elem, index) => orders.findIndex(obj => obj.email === elem.email) === index)
```

But this call took a very long time (my dataset is large) and it satisfies only the first operation of the SQL query.

What's the best way I should be going about this?

EDIT: I expect the output of the (SQL -> JS) to be the following:

```
[
  {email: 'test@test.com', month_acquired: 07, year_acquired: 2017},
  {email: 'test1@test1.com', month_acquired: 07, year_acquired: 2015}
]
```

Comment: Could you show what the result of the data should look like?

Comment: `new Map(items.sort((a,b) => b.daydate - a.daydate).map(v => [v.email, v.daydate]))` does everything but the `EXTRACT`. Assuming `daydate` is either a `Date` object or a timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up working for me:

```
  const res = o.reduce((r, o) => {
    const key = o.email
    const monthAcquired = parseInt(o.daydate.split('-')[1])
    const yearAcquired = parseInt(o.daydate.split('-')[0])
    if (!r[key]) {
      r[key] = { email: o.email, month_acquired: monthAcquired, year_acquired: yearAcquired }
    } else {
      if (r[key].year_acquired > yearAcquired) {
        r[key].year_acquired = yearAcquired
        r[key].month_acquired = monthAcquired
      } else {
        if (r[key].year_acquired === yearAcquired && r[key].month_acquired > monthAcquired) {
          r[key].year_acquired = yearAcquired
          r[key].month_acquired = monthAcquired
        }
      }
    }
    return r
  }, {})
```